# Why do we not store the min in any of the recursive clusters in a Van Emde Boas tree?

Tags: data-structures, trees, recursion, search-trees

I was reading the chapter of van Emde Boas in CLRS (page 547 section 20.3 3rd edition) and it says:

> Furthermore, the element stored in *min* does not appear in any of the recursive $vEB( \sqrt[\downarrow]{u})$ trees that the *cluster* array points to. The elements stored in a $vEB(u)$ tree *V*, therefore, are *V.min* plus all the elements recursively stored in the $vEB(\sqrt[\uparrow]{u})$ trees pointed to by *V.cluster*$[0..\sqrt[\uparrow]{u} - 1]$. Note that when a vEB tree contains two or more elements, we treat *min* and *max* differently: the element
>   stored in *min* does not appear in any of the clusters, but the element stored in *max* does.

However, I was not sure why that was true. Usually I put more details in my question but I don't understand why the min wouldn't appear recursively too just like in proto one. Does anyone understand the justification for that paragraph? Why do we treat the min and max differently? What is special about 2 or more?